# Style <th> with classes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble with HTML tables. My table looks like the following:

```
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="product-name">Produkt</th>
        <th class="product-price">Preis</th>
        <th class="product-quantity">Anzahl</th>
        <th class="product-subtotal">Summe</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to define with CSS that my `<th>` with all the classes get a `border-bottom{1px solid black;}`. Important is that only the `<th>`with the classes are styled, because I have `<td>`with the same classes and they shouldn't get the border. I hope you can understand me.

Comment: `table.shop_table.cart th {...}` doesn't do it?

Comment: Can you post your CSS code so we can see what we're working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty basic, just use your th tag with the class selector immediately following.. So it would look something like...

```
    th.product-remove,
    th.product-thumbnail,
    th.product-name,
    th.product-price,
    th.product-quantity,
    th.product-subtotal {
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
th
{
   /* add your styling here */
}
```

or, to limit to a specific class:

```
th.class-name
{
   /* add your styling here */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify that only th's with classes that starts with "product-" will have the border bottom

```
th[class^='product-'] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

uncoder is write with:

> or, to limit to a specific class:
>
> `th.class-name {    /* add your styling here */ }`

Though if you want to select all of your th with just one selector using class names you can do this:
`th[class*='product-'] { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }`

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to add a special class to the elements you want to style, like this:

```
<th class="product-remove product-bordered">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="product-thumbnail product-bordered">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="product-name product-bordered">Produkt</th>
<th class="product-price product-bordered">Preis</th>
<th class="product-quantity product-bordered">Anzahl</th>
<th class="product-subtotal product-bordered">Summe</th>

//CSS
.product-bordered {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

But at the end of the day it is your decision if you write a special class or not, the other answers have good solutions too.

Greetings from Germany